# how to login and create file in ec2 using java code

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I have aws ec2 instance, i need to connect to ec2 and create script and run the script in ec2 using java,can any one help me.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to connect to ec2 instance you can use ssh. 
If ec2 instance is in private subnet you will have to connect to it using bastion instance, otherwise you can connect directly using public ip address.
After you connected using ssh you can write whatewer script you want, or just copy it directly using scp.
In order to run java program make sure java is installed in your instance (run **java -version** command). If it is not installed you will have to install jvm first. The commands will be different depending on OS of your instance. Most probably it should be CentOS or Ubuntu.
After java is installed use  **java -jar *jarfilename*.jar** command to run your application.